# Display text outside Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, text, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I want to display some text (copyright) in the right corner (outside the modal) when a Bootstrap modal is opened.

How to do that?

(Sorry for my English, greethings from Germany ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the div modal-content create another div inside called modal-footer. Then in the class of the paragraph put pull-right.

Example:

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <p class="pull-right">Copyright stuff</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

The text will display in the bottom right corner of the modal.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my bay description, I want to have it in the right corner of the screen, outside the modal